# Unknown Device - FT232RL Driver - ESP8266

Tags: drivers, device-manager

I have installed the driver for a FTDI 232R board similar to this one...

[https://www.amazon.com/HiLetgo-Ft232rl-Serial-Adapter-Arduino/dp/B00IJXZQ7C/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1473792252&sr=1-1&keywords=ftdi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IJXZQ7C)

... and installed the driver for the FT232R chip found here ...

http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm

... and am trying to hook a ESP8266 to the FT232RL board.  The ESP8266 I purchased form amazon and can be found here...

[https://www.amazon.com/Addicore-ESP8266-Tranceiver-Antistatic-Compatible/dp/B00PA3UQNI/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1473792493&sr=1-2&keywords=esp8266](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PA3UQNI)

When the FT232 is connected to USB, Windows sees the board just fine and displays a COM port for me to send command via putty or other terminal program.  When I type, I see the light flicker on the FT232 board so it's getting my key strokes.

However, if I connect the ESP8266, the COM port disappears from the System Devices in Windows.  How can I force the COM port to stay when the ESP8266 is connected to the FT232 serial board?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you properly connected the FTDI and the ESP8266 check on this image to confirm http://i0.wp.com/makezine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ESP-01-FTDI_bb1-620x537.png?resize=620%2C537

Comment: Actually no.  I am missing the ground to GPIO 0.  Didn't realize that was neccessary.  I will try that when I get home and see if that helps.

Comment: That was it.  I've hooked it up like that and re-installed an older version of the FTDI drivers and I see the COM port.  Time to get the ESP8266 working.

Comment: Well, it kind of worked.  I believe the grounding of GPIO 0 puts the card into flash mode.  I just flashed a .bin file it (kinda by accident, didn't think it was going to work), but I can't communicate with it.  Directions say it should be 9600 baud.

Comment: Without offense did you connect RX with TX and TX with RX?

Comment: No offense taken.  RX goes to TX and TX goes to RX...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can communicate with my ESP8266 via the FTDI board now.  After burning another firmware that I knew defaulted to 9600 baud, I followed the advice I found at http://internetofhomethings.com/homethings/?p=396 and https://github.com/nabovarme/kamstrup-wifi/issues/38 and stuck the 470uf cap on the breadboard between the VCC and Ground rail and stuck .1uf cap from VCC to Ground on the esp8266 board.  I can issue AT commands using Putty.  I was getting errors issuing AT commmands and then Ctrl-J and Ctrl-M, but if I do commands and Ctrl-M and Ctrl-J I get the "OK" messages.  Also, I have to type do a slow Ctrl-M and Ctrl-J or I may get an error.  Hope this helps folks in the future.

UPDATE - Started getting the issue again.  Swapped USB cable, works fine.  There was a lot of inconsistent behavior until I swapped the USB cable.  I noticed the wire going into the USB connector is exposed.  Obviously the cable is hokey.  For future adventures with a similar situation, try another USB cable!